# display inline block doesnt work when i increase div width

Tags: jquery, html, css

[My site](http://kchang.myshopify.com/)

I currently have

```
<div class="main-sale">
  <div class="time-left">Sale Time Left: </div>
  <div class="sale-item">
    //Main Sale item
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slider-container">
  <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
      //Owl Slider
    </div>
</div>
```

The current width of .slider-container is 60%. When I try to increase it to 61%, it goes under the .sale-item. How come this happens even though i clearly have space for the width to increase?

Comment: You really need to post all the relevant code here. A link to your site is not sufficient and will not make this question be a long-standing source of advice and solutions for other users.

Comment: Need to see CSS in order to understand your problem, but if you are using inline-block then you should eliminate the white space in the HTML between the tags.

Comment: you need to start paying attention to instructions, including how Stack Overflow works and How to make questions (see http://stackoverflow.com/help seems it seems you don't know how), pay attention to code, accept answers and show some appreciation for all the help you're getting. It seems you think this is a free coding service and you don't even need to comply to the bare minimum etiquette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeGuy.jpg). There's a 50px margin on each side of the `.slider-container` div. You can reduce the value of these margins and then increase the width of the `.slider-container` div. Although I could increase the width of `.slider-container` div to `63%` and at `64%`, it moved down under the `main-sale` div.

You can add this code to your stylesheet:

```
.slider-container {
    margin: 0px 30px;
    width: 66.5%;
}
```

[image]